# Who is the oldest known political protester?

Tags: protests

According to [this article](https://www.romaniajournal.ro/gendarme-to-philosopher-mihai-sora-during-protests-scoot-over-old-man-second-lieutenant-asks-to-exit-the-gendarmerie/) probably the oldest Romanian protester is 101 years old:

> Philosopher Mihai Sora, aged 101, famous for attending numerous street
>   protests in the past year, recounted the incidents involving him and
>   the gen dares during the Wednesday’s manifestation in Victoriei
>   Square, Bucharest.

I am wondering if there is any reference (document) about an older protester. Restrictions:

- participation after 1900
- political protest
- participation out of his/her own will
- must have a minimum lucidity (e.g. understand the reasons for being at the protest)

*Note: age is considered at the moment of protest*

**Question:** Who is the oldest known political protester?

Comment: My apologies, but I VTCed and downvoted this question as "not useful". Could you please clarify why the answer - even if it can be legitimately obtained (since nobody tracks all protestors, it is likely that whatever answer you get won't be real); what would be the use to anyone to know that information?

Comment: @user4012 - since I want references, it does not have to be the oldest protester in a philosophical way, but a documented case. I cannot speak for other protests, but in Romania's case, his age was used to provide more power the protest: if he can participate to protests at 101, others can and should, he was invited to speak every time he was there etc.

Comment: Close votes - since I provided an example and I specifically want documented examples, the "cannot be verified" does not apply here.